# React + MUI + TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am currently trying to change the default colors of MUI TextField (text and border). I have failed with several approaches as mentioned by the official web site. Among all the solutions I have experimented, the most promising one is this one:

```
<TextField InputLabelProps={{ style: { color: 'white' } }} ...>
```

This solution changes the color of the text when unedited. As soon as I edit the text, the color takes it original value. I also tried this solution without any success:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      defaultProps: {
        style: { color: 'white'}
      }
    }
  }
});
```

After applying this theme, I had no changes. Did someone experimented the same issue ?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can make use of MUI color palette:

```
"primary" | "secondary" | "error" | "info" | "success" | "warning"

<TextField
  color="primary"
/>
```

These colors can be overwritten with a `ThemeProvider` and be used as the **border color** onFocus.

```
const getMuiTheme = () =>
  createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#FF0000" // red
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#00FF00" // green
      }
    }
  });


<ThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>
  <TextField />
  ...
</ThemeProvider>
```

You can then deal with the **input color** by using `sx` prop inside `TextField`:

```
sx={{
  input: {
    color: getMuiTheme().palette.secondary.main
  }
}}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit admiring-austin-hcxhvl]

**Edit:**
If you want the border to be permanently colored, **regardless of focus or hover** you can add this to the existing `sx` prop:

```
sx={{
  input: {
    color: getMuiTheme().palette.secondary.main
  },
  ".MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
    borderColor: `${getMuiTheme().palette.secondary.main} !important`
  }
}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx. I have already tried this solution. The color of the text and the border become white only if selected. Otherwise, it is dark.

Comment: I edited my answer, how about now?

Comment: Almost ! The text is still dark until it is selected. I have a better a result with my example below. But still, does not work as I wish.

Comment: I have finally found a solution to my issue, that I edit below. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This solution solves my issue:

```
const color = '#FFF';

const AppTextField = styled(TextField)({
    '& label': {
        color: color,
    },
    '& label.Mui-focused': {
        color: color,
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
        borderBottomColor: color
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
        color: color,
        '& fieldset': {
            borderColor: color
        },
        '&:hover fieldset': {
            borderColor: color
        },
        '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
            borderColor: color
        }
    }
});
```

Thx for your help.